# Insert into a table which has a dash in the name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-error-1064

I have a table called `concept-relation` and I want to insert into it.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sources); $i++) {
    $sourceID = $this->getConcpeptID($sources[$i]);
    $desID = $this->getConcpeptID($distinations[$i]);
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO concept-relation (relationID, firstConceptID, secondConceptID) VALUES (:rID, :sID, :dID)";
    $sth = $this->db->prepare($query2);
    $sth->execute(array(
        ':rID' => $relationID,
        ':sID' => $sourceID,
        'dID' => $desID
    ));
}
```

I got this syntax error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-relation (relationID, firstConceptID, secondConceptID) VALUES (' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mar7ba\models\ontology_model.php:86 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mar7ba\models\ontology_model.php(86): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mar7ba\controlers\Ontology.php(69): Ontology_Model->addRelation('jklljkljk', Array, Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mar7ba\libs\Bookstrap.php(42): Ontology->relationAdd() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mar7ba\index.php(13): Bootstrap->__construct() #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mar7ba\models\ontology_model.php on line 86

I tried to insert directly from MySQL and got error seems the same error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"-".relation (relationID, firstConceptID, secondConceptID) VALU' at line 1

The problem is because the table's name has dash in in, look how MySQL understand the query

```
INSERT INTO concept - relation(
    relationID,
    firstConceptID,
    secondConceptID
)
VALUES ( 3, 3, 3 )
```

It understands concept just and make "- relation" alone,

**Any help appreciated, but not changing my table's name:)**

Comment: using backtick does not change your table name, it just escape the table name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Enclosing identifiers with backtick makes reserved words/characters as valid identifiers in mysql.

So you should use

```
 `concept-relation`
```

The backtick (<kbd>`</kbd>)is the key at the top-left of this keyboard.

[image]

Comment: how can i found that charector before concept ? whice keyboard key ?

Comment: Pres the key left of `1` on English keyboard

Answer (score 4):

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `concept-relation` (relationID, firstConceptID, secondConceptID)
                VALUES (:rID, :sID, :dID)";
```

Comment: if u mean qoma , like this 'concpet-relation' so it doesn't work

Comment: it's not qoma - it's a back apostrophe (it's in the numeric row on your keyboard before `1`)

Comment: yes man it works , thank you very much , i will accept your answer after 6 mins

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
"INSERT INTO `concept-relation` (relationID, firstConceptID, secondConceptID) VALUES (:rID, :sID, :dID)";
```

Comment: what is that charector before concept ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO concept-relation (relationID, firstConceptID, secondConceptID)
                VALUES (:rID, :sID, :dID)";
```

Comment: the same errror , still the same