# When i inserted string "Jack - Jill" in mysql db it saved as "hello â€“ world"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

While inserting data "Jack - Jill" in mysql db, it saving as "Jack â€ Jill“, my problem is when i tried to display the string in  page its showing like "Jack �€� Jill", i am just botherd to display the string properly like "Jack - Jill", i tried have proper charactersets but not much of luck.

Comment: *"i tried have proper charactersets"* - what exactly does that mean, what exactly have you tried?

Comment: Please follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607041/mysql-insert-to-a-table-his-name-contains-dash

Comment: @deceze: having header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); in php, <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in HTML head and executing query mysql_query(SET NAMES utf-8)

Comment: Zeshan data is already inserted into db, my problem is displaying it not the insertion or table_name

Answer (score 0):

make sure you specify the charset used by your page to the database (and all its tables), and the other way around. i.e.:

Give your page a metatag and the script witing to the database a line that either validates that the charset is UTF-8 (example charset), or that it converts the chaarset to UTF-8

and give your database the same property, that it saves and reads data as UTF-8 (i use PHPMyAdmin, if you use such GUI tools too, its just a checkbox away).

hope i pointed you into the right direction